# Enlazar GUI con Algoritmo en Python

Tags: python, pyqt5

he tratado de enlazar un algoritmo para ver el ingreso o salida de un objeto para lo cual definí dos botones para el ingreso al programa, luego 2 botones S1 y S2 para ver la dirección del objeto(S1 Y S2 representan sensores, pero al momento de enlazar la interfaz con el algoritmo no he podido conectar los los botones con su respectiva función, dentro del código les he dejado a modo de comentario que falta definir "on_button_clicked" y el lugar donde deberían ser ejecutado, gracias por tomarse el tiempo en responder¡¡

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QPushButton, QDialog, QGroupBox, QVBoxLayout, QGridLayout,QLabel,QLineEdit,QButtonGroup,QLCDNumber 
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtGui 
from PyQt5.QtCore import QRect 
from PyQt5  import QtCore 
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap


class Window(QDialog):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__() #super??

        self.title = "PyQt5 Layout Managment"
        self.top = 100
        self.left = 300
        self.width = 800
        self.height = 600
        self.iconName="logo.png"

        self.InitWindow()
        #importar aqui

    def InitWindow(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon(self.iconName))
        self.setGeometry(self.left,self.top,self.width,self.height)

        self.Activated_program()
        self.Estructure()

        vbox=QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addWidget(self.groupBox)
        self.setLayout(vbox)     
        self.show()

    def Activated_program(self):
        self.groupBox0=QGroupBox("WELCOME TO THE PROGRAM")
        self.groupBox0.setFont(QtGui.QFont("BankGothic Md BT",13))
        gridLayout =QGridLayout() 

        self.button=QPushButton("ENTER", self)
        self.button.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon("on.png"))
        self.button.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(40,40))#Para modificar el tamaño del icono
        self.button.clicked.connect(lambda:self.acces(self.button))
        #self.button.clicked.connect(self.RunTimer)    
        gridLayout.addWidget(self.button,0,0)

        self.button0=QPushButton("EXIT", self)
        self.button0.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon("off.png"))
        self.button0.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(40,40))
        self.button0.clicked.connect(lambda:self.acces(self.button0))
        gridLayout.addWidget(self.button0,1,0)

        self.groupBox0.setLayout(gridLayout)        

    def Sensor_Activated(self):
        self.groupBox1=QGroupBox("Is sensor 1 activated ?")
        self.groupBox1.setFont(QtGui.QFont("BankGothic Md BT",13))
        self.vbox1=QVBoxLayout()

        self.buttongroup = QButtonGroup()
        ##self.buttongroup.buttonClicked[int].connect(self.on_button_clicked)<---FALTA DEFINIR

        self.button1=QPushButton("Activated S1", self)
        self.button1.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon("on.png"))
        self.button1.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(40,40))#Para modificar el tamaño del icono
        self.button1.clicked.connect(lambda:self.selec(self.button1))
        
        #self.button1.clicked.connect(self.RunTimer)    
        self.vbox1.addWidget(self.button1)                

        self.button2=QPushButton("Disabled S1", self)
        self.button2.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon("off.png"))
        self.button2.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(40,40))
        self.button2.clicked.connect(lambda:self.selec(self.button2))
        
        self.vbox1.addWidget(self.button2)

        self.label1=QLabel("sensed values") # ¿QLabel(self)?
        self.label1.setFont(QtGui.QFont("BankGothic Md BT",13))
        self.vbox1.addWidget(self.label1)

        self.lcd1=QLCDNumber()
        self.lcd1.setStyleSheet("background-color: light blue")
        self.vbox1.addWidget(self.lcd1)        

        self.setLayout(self.vbox1)
        self.groupBox1.setLayout(self.vbox1)

    def Estructure(self):
        self.groupBox=QGroupBox("Sensor Activation")
        self.groupBox.setFont(QtGui.QFont("BankGothic Md BT",16))
        self.gridLayout =QGridLayout()
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.groupBox0,0,0,1,-1)

        self.groupBox.setLayout(self.gridLayout)

    def acces(self,b):

        if b==self.button:
            print ("clicked 1 button is "+b.text())
            self.button.setEnabled(False)
            #self.button0.setEnabled(False)
            self.Sensor_Activated()
            self.Enter_Value()
            self.Display()
            self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.groupBox1,1,0,1,1)
            self.groupBox.setLayout(self.gridLayout)                        

        elif b==self.button0:
            print ("clicked 1 button is "+b.text())
            self.button.setEnabled(False)
            exit()

    def selec(self,c):

        if c==self.button1:
            print ("clicked 1 button is "+b.text())
            self.buttongroup.addButton(button1, 1)
            self.buttongroup.addButton(button2, 2)

            ###-->Deberia esta enlazado con estas funciones
            if button2 is self.buttongroup.button(id):
                self.label1.setText(" Ingreso 1 ")
                self.lcd.display("1")

            elif button1 is self.buttongroup.button(id):
                self.label1.setText(" No ingreso nadie")

        elif c==self.button2:            
            print ("clicked 1 button is "+b.text())
            self.buttongroup.addButton(button1, 1)
            self.buttongroup.addButton(button2, 2)

            ###-->Deberia esta enlazado con estas funciones
            if button1 is self.buttongroup.button(id):
                self.label1.setText(" Salio 1 ")
                self.lcd.display("-1")

            elif button2 is self.buttongroup.button(id):
                self.label1.setText(" No salio nadie")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    App=QApplication(sys.argv)
    window=Window()
    sys.exit(App.exec())
```

Answer (score 0):

No estoy seguro de que te entiendo correctamente, pero prueba el siguiente ejemplo:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QPushButton, QDialog, QGroupBox, QVBoxLayout, QGridLayout,QLabel,QLineEdit,QButtonGroup,QLCDNumber 
from PyQt5.QtCore import QRect 
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap


class Window(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__() #super??
        self.title = "PyQt5 Layout Managment"
        self.top = 100
        self.left = 300
        self.width = 800
        self.height = 600
        self.iconName = "logo.png"

        self.InitWindow()
        #importar aqui

    def InitWindow(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon(self.iconName))
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)

        self.Activated_program()
        self.Estructure()

        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addWidget(self.groupBox)
        self.setLayout(vbox)     
        self.show()

    def Activated_program(self):
        self.groupBox0 = QGroupBox("WELCOME TO THE PROGRAM")
        self.groupBox0.setFont(QtGui.QFont("BankGothic Md BT", 13))
        gridLayout = QGridLayout() 

        self.button = QPushButton("ENTER", self)
        self.button.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon("on.png"))
        self.button.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(40,40))#Para modificar el tamaño del icono
        self.button.clicked.connect(lambda: self.acces(self.button))
        #self.button.clicked.connect(self.RunTimer)    
        gridLayout.addWidget(self.button, 0, 0)

        self.button0 = QPushButton("EXIT", self)
        self.button0.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon("off.png"))
        self.button0.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(40, 40))
        self.button0.clicked.connect(lambda: self.acces(self.button0))
        gridLayout.addWidget(self.button0, 1, 0)

        self.groupBox0.setLayout(gridLayout)        

    def Sensor_Activated(self):
        self.groupBox1 = QGroupBox("Is sensor 1 activated ?")
        self.groupBox1.setFont(QtGui.QFont("BankGothic Md BT",13))
        self.vbox1 = QVBoxLayout()

        self.buttongroup = QButtonGroup()
###        
        self.id = 1  # ?
        self.buttongroup.buttonClicked[int].connect(self.on_button_clicked) # <---FALTA DEFINIR
        

        self.button1 = QPushButton("Activated S1", self)
        self.button1.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon("on.png"))
        self.button1.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(40, 40))   # Para modificar el tamaño del icono
        self.button1.clicked.connect(lambda: self.selec(self.button1))
        
        #self.button1.clicked.connect(self.RunTimer)    
        self.vbox1.addWidget(self.button1)                

        self.button2=QPushButton("Disabled S1", self)
        self.button2.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon("off.png"))
        self.button2.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(40, 40))
        self.button2.clicked.connect(lambda: self.selec(self.button2))
        
        self.vbox1.addWidget(self.button2)

        self.label1 = QLabel("sensed values")                     # ¿QLabel(self)?
        self.label1.setFont(QtGui.QFont("BankGothic Md BT",13))
        self.vbox1.addWidget(self.label1)

        self.lcd1 = QLCDNumber()
        self.lcd1.setStyleSheet("background-color: lightblue")    # lightblue
        self.vbox1.addWidget(self.lcd1)        

# ???       self.setLayout(self.vbox1)
        self.groupBox1.setLayout(self.vbox1)

    def Estructure(self):
        self.groupBox = QGroupBox("Sensor Activation")
        self.groupBox.setFont(QtGui.QFont("BankGothic Md BT",16))
        self.gridLayout = QGridLayout()
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.groupBox0,0,0,1,-1)
        self.groupBox.setLayout(self.gridLayout)

    def acces(self, b):
        if b == self.button:
            print ("clicked 1 button is "+b.text())
            self.button.setEnabled(False)
            #self.button0.setEnabled(False)
            self.Sensor_Activated()
###
# ???           self.Enter_Value()
# ???           self.Display()
            self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.groupBox1,1, 0, 1, 1)
# ???           self.groupBox.setLayout(self.gridLayout)                        

        elif b == self.button0:
            print ("clicked 1 button is "+b.text())
            self.button.setEnabled(False)
            exit()

    def selec(self,c):
        if c == self.button1:
            print ("- clicked 1 button is " + c.text())              # c
            self.buttongroup.addButton(self.button1, 1)              # self.
            self.buttongroup.addButton(self.button2, 2)              # self.

            ###-->Deberia esta enlazado con estas funciones
            if self.button2 is self.buttongroup.button(self.id):     # id ???
                self.label1.setText(" Ingreso 1 ")
                self.lcd1.display("1")                               # lcd1
            elif self.button1 is self.buttongroup.button(self.id):   # id ???
                self.label1.setText(" No ingreso nadie")

        elif c == self.button2:            
            print ("clicked 1 button is " + c.text())                 # c
            self.buttongroup.addButton(self.button1, 1)
            self.buttongroup.addButton(self.button2, 2)

            ###-->Deberia esta enlazado con estas funciones
            if self.button1 is self.buttongroup.button(self.id):      # id  ???
                self.label1.setText(" Salio 1 ")
                self.lcd1.display("-1")                               # lcd1

            elif self.button2 is self.buttongroup.button(self.id):    # id  ???
                self.label1.setText(" No salio nadie")

# +++
    def on_button_clicked(self, id):                                  # +++
        print(id)                                                     # +++
        self.id = id                                                  # +++


if __name__ == "__main__":
    App=QApplication(sys.argv)
    window=Window()
    sys.exit(App.exec())
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]